# what does _model stand for in symfony/propel?

Tags: symfony1, propel

I change schema.yml from time to time and execute:

```
symfony propel:build-all-load
```

but the lib/_model and lb/model do not reflect my changes and cause: Call to undefined method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems strange - did you do `symfony cc` (clear cache) afterwards?

Have you also tried doing `symfony propel:build-model` on its own to make sure the model files are being regenerated OK?

Comment: if you've added classes, you need to clear the cache as symfony builds a load of auto-load info up from your directory structure which it won't rebuild unless you clear it.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, clear the cache

```
symfony cc
```

Then try using

```
symfony propel:build-forms
```

beforehand.